# Android: MVP: Restore state. Is it a good solution to store data for view in the presenter?

Tags: android, mvp

I have a view(Activity) with imageView and textView.
When I click on imageView then in the textView show how many time I click on the image.
I use pattern MVP to solve this task.

And as result, all work fine. OK. Nice.

But have one more task - to restore view state after rotate screen.

To solve this task I use the next approach:
1. Create Presenter as Singleton
2. I Presenter I have variable

```
private int countClick;
```

3. When clicking ImageView on the View I call `presenter.clickLike()`, increment it and call View method

   showCountOfClick()
4. In the Presenter

   public void clickLike() {
       countClick++;
       view.showCountOfClick(countClick + "");
   }
5. Also in Presenter I have method

   ```
   @Override
   public void viewIsReady() {
   view.showCountOfClick(countClick + "");
   }
   ```

This method call from View in `onCreate()` method()

6. In the View set text in `TextView` with the count of clicks.

   public void showCountOfClick(String text) {
     textView.setText(text)
   }

Done.

So as result the count of click shows correct when rotating screen.
And a bonus I do not need in View to override method `protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` because all work is done in Presenter.

Question:
Is it a good solution?

Answer (score -1):

Your `Activity` (normally) is going to be destroyed and recreated by the system on configuration changes. So it is not a good idea to hold a reference to it in a singleton. There are multiple solutions I prefere in this case:

- Use the `onSaveInstanceState`, you can forward this call to your Presenter for handling
- Use SharedPreferences to store data in your Presenter
- Use [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html)